# Lumen / Composer not installing all non-dev dependencies with --no-dev

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, lumen

I'm having issues understanding why some composer dependencies aren't being included in `autoload_psr4.php` when running `composer install --no-dev` using lumen.

Here's the require section from my `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.11.3",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
        "my-company/my-package": "~1.1",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.8.*"
}
```

My understanding is that the dependency chain is: lumen-framework depends on illuminate/auth (plus all of the other illuminate/* packages), which in turn is replaced by laravel/framework, as indicated by this (just a sample, this actually outputs all of the illuminate packages):

```
$ composer why laravel/framework
laravel/framework        v5.8.35  replaces  illuminate/auth (self.version)
...
laravel/lumen-framework  v5.8.13  requires  illuminate/auth (5.8.*)
...
```

The problem is that when deploying out to a server, we run `composer install --no-dev` so that dependencies used just for development aren't included. (phpunit, mockery, a few others). When doing that, it looks like some non-dev dependencies are also being removed, some rather import things like nesbot/carbon, monolog/monolog, psr/container.

Running `composer install` puts those dependencies back in to composer's `autoload_psr4.php` file. However, if I take all of my dev dependencies out of require-dev and put them in the require section, I see the exact same behavior? Why? Is this an upstream issue with how either lumen or laravel/frameworks are declaring their dependencies, or is there something I can look for locally that I'm doing wrong?

For further information, below is a list of the stuff present in `autoload_psr4.php` when running `composer install` but not there after `composer install --no-dev` with none of the dependencies inside of require-dev. I think all of these source back to `laravel/framework` when ran against `composer why`:

```
// None of these are present after running $ composer install --no-dev, but are there when running plain composer install

'TijsVerkoyen\\CssToInlineStyles\\' => array($vendorDir . '/tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles/src'),
'Symfony\\Polyfill\\Iconv\\' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/polyfill-iconv'),
'Symfony\\Contracts\\Translation\\' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/translation-contracts'),
'Symfony\\Component\\Translation\\' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/translation'),
'Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/routing'),
'Symfony\\Component\\CssSelector\\' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/css-selector'),
'Opis\\Closure\\' => array($vendorDir . '/opis/closure/src'),
'League\\Flysystem\\' => array($vendorDir . '/league/flysystem/src'),
'Egulias\\EmailValidator\\' => array($vendorDir . '/egulias/email-validator/EmailValidator'),
'Doctrine\\Common\\Lexer\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/lexer/lib/Doctrine/Common/Lexer'),
'Doctrine\\Common\\Inflector\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/inflector/lib/Doctrine/Common/Inflector'),
'Carbon\\' => array($vendorDir . '/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon'),
```

I was also able to locate [this github issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/8163) in composer still open from May which sounds close to my issue, but not quite matching.

**Update**: We were able to stop the issue from happening after downgrading composer from 1.9.1 to 1.6.3. For some reason, though, laravel/framework still shows up as a replacement when inspecting any of the illuminate/* packages with `composer why`.

Comment: Not related, but why is there `laravel/framework` package in your Lumen app? Shouldn't it be one _or_ the other?

Comment: @kerbholz That's just how it resolves (I think)... the only one in _my_ composer.json is `laravel/lumen-framework`, and [this](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.8/composer.json) is it's composer.json. When I do the `composer why laravel/framework` it shows the output of laravel/framework replacing all of those illuminate packages.

Comment: Hm, ok, thanks, was just wondering. I created a new Lumen (6) project using `lumen new test` to take a look and found that strange. When running `composer why laravel/framework` I get "_[InvalidArgumentException] Could not find package "laravel/framework" in your project_" and I _think_ there should only be either `laravel/framework` _or_ `laravel/lumen-framework` in your app, maybe one of your packages was made for Laravel only and is messing things up. Sorry I couldn't be of any help, good luck.

Comment: @kerbholz Just did the same with lumen 5.8 and got the same output, so you may be on to something...